# How can I correctly sort a list of elements in Python?

Tags: python, list, sortedlist

I am ordering a list of items that I replace with new ones, but by changing the letters by an equivalent in number and then ordering it, it cuts the order and does it in parts.

```
for (i) in range(len(unico)):
    if unico[i] == 'A':
        unico[i] = '14'
    elif unico[i] == 'D':
        unico[i] = '10'
    elif unico[i] == 'J':
        unico[i] = '11'
    elif unico[i] == 'Q':
        unico[i] = '12'
    elif unico[i] == 'K':
        unico[i] = '13'

for (i) in range(len(unico2)):
    if unico2[i] == 'A':
        unico2[i] = '14'
    elif unico2[i] == 'D':
        unico2[i] = '10'
    elif unico2[i] == 'J':
        unico2[i] = '11'
    elif unico2[i] == 'Q':
        unico2[i] = '12'
    elif unico2[i] == 'K':
        unico2[i] = '13'   

repetido, repetido2, unico, unico2 = 
    sorted(repetido, reverse=True), sorted(repetido2, reverse=True), 
    sorted(unico, reverse=True), sorted(unico2, reverse=True)

print (unico,unico2)
```

I was expecting this output:

```
['14', '13', '10','8','4','3'] ['14', '13', '12', '10', '7', '6', '5']
```

..but this is what I am getting:

```
['8', '4', '3', '14', '13', '10'] ['7', '6', '5', '14', '13', '12', '10']
```

Comment: Hola, en este sitio las preguntas se hacen en inglés, las preguntas en español las puedes hacer aqui: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is in Spanish, such questions belong in: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

Your python code is behaving correctly. You have a list of **strings**. So, `sorted()` sorts the list by comparing them as a string. As `'8'` is greater than all other element, so appears in front of the list.

What you want, is to compare the elements of the list as integer. You can pass the `key` attribute of `sort()` to return the element as integer like this -

```
unico = ['3', '4', '8', '10', '14', '13']
unico.sort(key=lambda x: int(x), reverse=True)
print(unico)
```

Output:

> ['14', '13', '10', '8', '4', '3']

The code uses a lambda function to convert string element to integer during sorting but the element itself remains unchanged. Another thing is you are overriding your list after sort. So, you can just use `sort()` method of list instead of `sorted()`.